# How to match table element in regex

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to match `"state_name"` in this

```
"STATE:</th><td>state_name</td>";

and i tried using this:
$pattern = "/STATE.*(\w+)\s$/";
```

But it doesn't work. I am sorry I am pretty new to regexes...help is appreciated!

Comment: Well, what's a list of different contexts it could appear in? Will it always be surrounded by `<td>` and `</td>`, immediately after `STATE:</th>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$pattern = "~STATE:</th><td>([^<]*)</td>~"
```

[(disclaimer)](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)